# What's the Maximum Value of smallint(6) unsigned in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, types

What's the maximum value of `smallint(6) unsigned` in MySQL?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

According to [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html), the maximum value of an unsigned smallint is **65535**.

The `(6)` portion has no effect on the allowed range of the column; it only affects the display of the column in the MySQL command line interface.

Answer (score 5):

An smallint unsigned max value is 65535 and uses 2 bytes

[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)